# Problema a gravar o valor do texto da checkBox na minha base de dados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Querias guardar os dias da semana seleccionados pelo utilizador, guardando o conteúdo da label como string.

O que chega ao controlador quando seleccionei todas as checkBox

```
Domingo false
Segunda-Feira false
Terça-Feira false
Quarta-Feira
```

queria guardar como `string` o texto da *label* da *checkbox* na minha base de dados, e descartar os "falses".

Controlador:

```
private MultiSelectList GetDias(string[] selectedValues)
{
    List<DiasSemana> Dias = new List<DiasSemana>()
    {
        new DiasSemana() { ID = 0, Dia= "Domingo" },
        new DiasSemana() { ID = 1, Dia= "Segunda-Feira" },
        new DiasSemana() { ID = 2, Dia= "Terça-Feira" },
        new DiasSemana() { ID = 3, Dia= "Quarta-Feira" },
        new DiasSemana() { ID = 4, Dia= "Quinta-Feira" },
        new DiasSemana() { ID = 5, Dia= "Sexta-Feira" },
        new DiasSemana() { ID = 6, Dia= "Sábado-Feira" },
    };

    return new MultiSelectList(Dias, "ID", "Dia", selectedValues);
}
```

Get:

```
public ActionResult CriarGrupo()
{     
    // acedendo a um conjunto de valores de uma classe
    ViewBag.Daylist = GetDias(null);

    return View();
}
```

Post:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CriarGrupo([Bind(Include = "GrupoID,AnoPastoral,HoraInicio,DiaSessao,AnoCatequese,LetraGrupo,Sala,Observacoes")] Grupo grupo, params string[] SelectDias)
{
    grupo.DiaSessao = SelectDias[0] + SelectDias[1] + SelectDias[2] + SelectDias[3] + SelectDias[4] + SelectDias[5] + SelectDias[6];

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Grupo.Add(grupo);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(grupo);
}
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DiaSessao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @foreach (var item in (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.Daylist)
        {
            //  @Html.CheckBox("SelectDias", new { @class = "checkbox-inline", @value = @item.Text })
            <input type="checkbox" name="SelectDias" value="@item.Text" class="checkbox-inline" />
            @Html.Label(item.Text, new { @class = "control-label" })

            <br />
        }
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode guardar os números de cada dia como uma `string`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CriarGrupo([Bind(Include = "GrupoID,AnoPastoral,HoraInicio,DiaSessao,AnoCatequese,LetraGrupo,Sala,Observacoes")] Grupo grupo, params string[] SelectDias)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        grupo.DiaSessao = (SelectDias[0] == "true" ? "1 " : "") + 
                          (SelectDias[1] == "true" ? "2 " : "") + 
                          (SelectDias[2] == "true" ? "3 " : "") + 
                          (SelectDias[3] == "true" ? "4 " : "") + 
                          (SelectDias[4] == "true" ? "5 " : "") + 
                          (SelectDias[5] == "true" ? "6 " : "") + 
                          (SelectDias[6] == "true" ? "7 " : "");

        db.Grupo.Add(grupo);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(grupo);
}
```

Na hora de montar o campo do `form`:

```
var grupo = db.Grupos.FirstOrDefault();
ViewBag.Daylist = GetDias(grupo.DiaSessao.Split());
```